# Importing error in python package skimage

Tags: python, image-processing, filter, wavelet, scikit-image

I want to use **skimage.restoration.denoise_wavelet** to denoise a image. But problem occurs on importing.

`from skimage.restoration import denoise_nl_means,denoise_wavelet`

`ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-161a32d32528> in <module>()
----> 1 from skimage.restoration import denoise_nl_means,denoise_wavelet
ImportError: cannot import name denoise_wavelet`

There is no problem in importing **denoise_nl_means** which is in the same category with **denoise_wavelet**. It doesn't make sense.

I used **pip** for installing and updating the skimage package and **jupyter notebook** for coding.
I installed all requirements before installing scikit-image 0.12.3. The requirement items I installed were:

`matplotlib 1.5.1,numpy 1.11.1,scipy 0.18.1,six 1.10.0,networkx 1.11,pillow 3.4.1,dask 0.10.0,PyWavelets 0.4.0`.

Answer (score 0):

As you installed this library with pip, it probably installed the latest stable release, which is something within the **0.12** branch.

There are different documentations for different versions of scikit-learn.
**The function** which you want to import **does not exist yet in any stable branch** if we interpret the following correctly:

[Search for function-name in docs of development-branch](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/search.html?q=denoise_wavelet&check_keywords=yes&area=default): OK!

[Search for function-name in docs of 0.12 branch](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/search.html?q=denoise_wavelet&check_keywords=yes&area=default) No hits!

Sadly, the docs of scikit-image do not say when a function was added to the library (as done by scipy).

Further analysis can be done on [github + blame here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blame/2f71b5787662ce7589bb878c55359cd076f84c83/skimage/restoration/_denoise.py).

So if you need this function, grab the development-branch and install from sources! Always read the corresponding doc-versions!

Comment: y, the function I need, it only exists in the dev branch 0.13.x.

Answer (score 0):

used the following command:

```
pip install -U https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/archive/master.zip
```